# Migrating disqus comments into drupal comments

Tags: 7, migrations, comments

After having refactored my site disqus comments do not match with their original nodes (despites they share the same path alias) and I am considering leaving disqus, as I didn't manage to fix the problem.

I would like to migrate from disqus to drupal and although I have seen that disqus offers an export feature that generates a xml file (https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472149-comments-export). Unfortunately I haven't been able to import that file into drupal, as the [disqus module](http://drupal.org/project/disqus) had this functionallity on D6 only and [this sandbox project](https://drupal.org/sandbox/sanchiz/1999128) is abandoned and does not work (I guess disqus changed their API)

Maybe migrate module or [feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) could handle that, but I haven't found any documentation on how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: The following code shows disqus' xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<disqus xmlns="http://disqus.com" xmlns:dsq="http://disqus.com/disqus-internals" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://disqus.com/api/schemas/1.0/disqus.xsd http://disqus.com/api/schemas/1.0/disqus-internals.xsd">
    <!-- First defines the threads = drupal nodes -->
    <thread dsq:id="3225849642">
        <id>node/400</id> <!-- This nid has changed after migration--> 
        <forum>carloscamara</forum>
        <category dsq:id="670543" />
        <link>http://carloscamara.es/blog/2014/11/15/experiencia-como-usuario-de-un-fairphone</link><!-- This path is the same after migration--> 
        <title>Experiencia como usuario de un Fairphone</title>
        <message />
        <createdAt>2014-11-14T23:52:16Z</createdAt>
        <author>
            <email>some email</email>
            <name>some name</name>
            <isAnonymous>false</isAnonymous>
            <username>ccamara</username>
        </author>
        <ipAddress>some IP</ipAddress>
        <isClosed>false</isClosed>
        <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
    </thread>

    <!-- Posts are like drupal comments are later defined and related to threads referencing their thread dsq:id -->

    <post dsq:id="2247159473">
        <id />
        <message><![CDATA[<p>Estoy muy interesada en comprarme el Fairphonr 1, y espero no llegar tarde. ¿Dónde puedo comprarlo?</p>]]></message>
        <createdAt>2015-09-10T23:05:08Z</createdAt>
        <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
        <isSpam>false</isSpam>
        <author>
            <email>Another email</email>
            <name>Another name</name>
            <isAnonymous>true</isAnonymous>
        </author>
        <ipAddress>Another IP</ipAddress>
        <thread dsq:id="3225849642" />
    </post>

    <!-- This comment is a child of another comment -->
    <post dsq:id="2247642804">
        <id />
        <message><![CDATA[<p>Hola, pues siento decirte que los Fairphone 1 se agotaron y no van a hacer más, así que me temo que solo quedan dos opciones: o comprar el Fairphone 2 (mucho mejor, pero también más caro) o comprar uno de segunda mano.</p>]]></message>
        <createdAt>2015-09-11T07:45:30Z</createdAt>
        <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
        <isSpam>false</isSpam>
        <author>
            <email>some email</email>
            <name>some name</name>
            <isAnonymous>false</isAnonymous>
            <username>ccamara</username>
        </author>
        <ipAddress>some IP</ipAddress>
        <thread dsq:id="3225849642" /> <!-- This is the parent's node -->
        <parent dsq:id="2247159473" /> <!-- This is the parent's comment -->
    </post>
</disqus>
```

Comment: does this xml file give you the Node ID (nid) of each comment?

Comment: yes, it provides both node/id and path alias. Why are you asking that?

Comment: because it's crucial.

Comment: Could you be so kind to explain why is so crucial and what can I do with it?

Comment: It's crucial because it tells you what comment belongs to what node (article).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need [Feeds Comment Processor](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_comment_processor) and [Feeds XPath Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) because your xml does not use the typical rss title, author, and url tags.

[Here is an example](https://www.drupal.org/node/1045026) on how to set up the xpath parser.

Comment: Thank you! I did what you suggested, although I didn't succeed with it, most likely because I never worked with xpath parser and I might have not made a correct mapping (or processor's configuration). That's my processor configuration: http://pastebin.com/7N3tR3pQ (I'm not sure with lines 24-30) and here's the xml defintion: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472149-comments-export

Can you find any errors on my mapping or configuration?

Comment: it's not working because you haven't set a **Context** in your **XPATH PARSER SETTINGS**. Try using `/disqus` as your Context.

Comment: your name needs to be like this, `thread/author/name` & `post/author/name`

Comment: also change `post/dsq:id` to `post/@dsq:id`

Comment: Thank you again, you're being really helpful. With your changes (and this link http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) I've been able to progress a little bit, although I haven't been able to import anything yet as I haven't been able to map cid (see error here: http://pastebin.com/WFwhUaax). However, I'm afraid I will have problems in order to determine each comment's node, as disqus xml defines first a thread (that would be drupal node) and then a post (drupal comment), so they are not nested.  Any idea?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about comment id (cid) as feeds will auto generate one. So which one is the node id? `<thread>1</thread>`? or `<id>3</id>` or `<post dsq:id="2">` I cannot tell by just looking at the example that you provided.

Comment: You're right about cid. As per the node... I have edited the description with a sample code. As you'll see I can't use original nid, as it has changed, but I can get the path. Additionally I do not know how can I relate comments to nodes, as xml is not nested (see code again)

Comment: @CarlosCámara **[Now that's what I call a sticky situation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkmV9mnUTC4)**. What I would do is copy your code and paste it on Notepad or Excel and replace 3225849642 with the node id. Ex: if the node id is 400 then `<thread dsq:id="400" />` so now your `<posts>` have node ids. Then save the modified xml file in your C: drive and use upload instead of url for your feed.

Comment: With Notepad++ or Excel use the find and replace feature. So it replaces all 3225849642 automatically for you.

Comment: Yes, that's a sticky situation (and thanks for your help again). Hum... I think I could get node id using the "Node id from title" available field from the xpath parser's mapping (although I am not sure what to write I guess something like `/thread/title` ), but what bothers me is how to relate each thread with its content, as they are not nested and all the syntax examples refer to nested nodes.